# Concatenating variable with integer returning NULL value in Snowflake Stored Procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to fetch values from Information schema and load them to a table based on conditions by fetching dynamically. However, the DEFAULT_VAL seem to be NULL because of which am unable to construct the query properly to insert into the table.

Please advise how I can concatenate variable with a value that was returned from SQL execute.

```
var tbl_qry = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: `select TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, case WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%INT%' THEN 'INT' 
                                            WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%TIME%' OR DATA_TYPE LIKE '%DATE%'THEN 'DATE' AS ACTION
                                            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;`})

while tbl_query.next()
{
    if name == 'EMP'
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL = -1
    }
    else if name == 'SAL'
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL = -2
    }
    else
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL=-3
    }
    
    var COL_LIST = ' (' ;
    var VAL_LIST = ' VALUES (' ;
    
    var TABLE_NAME = tbl_query.getColumnValue(1);
    var ORDINAL_POSITION = tbl_query.getColumnValue(2);
    var ACTION = tbl_query.getColumnValue(3);
    
    if (ORDINAL_POSITION > 1)
    {
        var COL_LIST = COL_LIST + ',' ;
        var VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + ',' ;
    }
    if (ACTION_FLAG == 'DATE')
    {
        VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `CONCAT('"','9999-12-31','"')`;
    }
    else
    {
        VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `DEFAULT_VAL`;
    }
    
    var COL_LIST = COL_LIST + COLUMN_NAME;

    
    INSERT_SQL_CMD := 'INSERT INTO VAL_TBL'|| COL_LIST || VAL_LIST ;
    
    snowflake.execute ({sqlText: INSERT_SQL_CMD});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not collecting the value of the `name` column. You need to get that from the `ResultSet` object. Also, the if statement comparisons need to be inside parenthesis. Finally, you need to collect the `ordinal_position` the same way this shows how to collect `name` (keeping in mind column names are case sensitive in Snowflake):

```
var tbl_qry = snowflake.execute({ sqlText: `select TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION, case WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%INT%' THEN 'INT' 
                                            WHEN DATA_TYPE LIKE '%TIME%' OR DATA_TYPE LIKE '%DATE%'THEN 'DATE' AS ACTION
                                            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;`})

var name;

while tbl_query.next()
{
    name = tbl_qry.getColumnValue("name");

    if (name == 'EMP')
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL = -1
    }
    else if (name == 'SAL')
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL = -2
    }
    else
    {
        DEFAULT_VAL=-3
    }

...
```

Edit: The DEFAULT_VAL is being concatenated as a string literal.

```
VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `DEFAULT_VAL`;
```

The above is concatenating VAL_LIST with the string literal "DEFAULT_VAL". You can simply remove the backticks to concatenate them. If the DEFAULT_VAL is numeric and concatenation causes problems, you can change to using a template literal:

```
VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `${DEFAULT_VAL}`;
```

Comment: Thanks, Greg ! Let me try that. Also, ‘VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `DEFAULT_VAL`; doesn’t get assigned with -1 value

Comment: ACTION_FLAG is another one that needs to be collected from the ResultSet using `tbl_query.getColumnValue('ACTION')` (I don't see a column named ACTION_FLAG, so I think this is the one.) Also, I don't see where `DEFAULT_VAL` is being set. That needs to be collected from the ResultSet too.

Comment: Yes, the column is ACTION. You are correct. Any idea how I can concatenate -1 with string VAL_LIST? VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST + `DEFAULT_VAL`;

Comment: I updated my answer for the `DEFAULT_VAL` at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, Greg ! I am trying to hold column names and column values in COL LIST and VAL LIST. With this approach, am able to hold only the last column. The loop doesn't seem to work.